# Given commutative group $G$, to show that subset $H \subseteq G$ containing only those elements of $G$ whose order divides $10$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H$ will contain elements having orders among $\{1, 2, 5, 10\}$. Now if we take any of these elements or their composition, how can we proceed to prove that their closure will lie inside $H$ only, and their identity as well as inverse also exists in $H$? I understand that somewhere we can utilize the commutative property but I'm not able to figure it out.

Can someone please point me out to anything trivial which I might be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: what do you know about $o\left(a\cdot b\right)$?

Comment: Thanks! figured it out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $a,b \in H$, then $(ab)^{10}=a^{10}\times b^{10}=e$ (This is true as $G$ is commutative) , hence order of $ab$ divides $10$, hence $ab \in H$. I guess the rest is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)